# Will Apache on Windows run versions of PHP compiled with VC9 (PHP 5.3.6+)?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

The new versions of PHP for windows are only offically released compiled using VC++9, however to the best of my knowledge Apache on Windows has only ever worked with the VC6 builds (at least that's all anyone ever ships with).

Does this mean I'll be unable to use the latest versions of PHP on an Apache server without compiling PHP myself? Is there some extension for Apache on windows that will allow it to run the latest versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a CGI, it doesn't matter what compiler version is in use.